# Can't install pyautgui on PyCharm MacOS Big Sur 11.3.1

Tags: pycharm, pyautogui, macos-big-sur

When installing pyautogui on Pycharm's system preferences, I keep getting this error: "Could not build wheels for pymsgbox, pyscreeze which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly" as shown below. Why is this happening? I tried several ways such as installing individual files on the Pycharm terminal but to no avail.

```
Collecting PyAutoGUI
  Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.52.tar.gz (55 kB)
Collecting pymsgbox
  Using cached PyMsgBox-1.0.9.tar.gz (18 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1
  Using cached PyTweening-1.0.3.zip (15 kB)
Collecting pyscreeze>=0.1.21
  Using cached PyScreeze-0.1.27.tar.gz (25 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Collecting pygetwindow>=0.0.5
  Using cached PyGetWindow-0.0.9.tar.gz (9.7 kB)
Collecting mouseinfo
  Using cached MouseInfo-0.1.3.tar.gz (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-core in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from PyAutoGUI) (7.2)
Collecting pyobjc
  Using cached pyobjc-7.2-py3-none-any.whl (3.0 kB)
Collecting Pillow>=6.2.1; python_version == "3.8"
  Using cached Pillow-8.2.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (2.8 MB)
Collecting pyrect
  Using cached PyRect-0.1.4.tar.gz (15 kB)
Collecting pyperclip
  Using cached pyperclip-1.8.2.tar.gz (20 kB)
Collecting rubicon-objc
  Using cached rubicon_objc-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_ScreenSaver-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (6.2 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-OSAKit==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_OSAKit-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.5 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-NaturalLanguage==7.2; platform_release >= "18.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_NaturalLanguage-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.2 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AdSupport==7.2; platform_release >= "18.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_AdSupport-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.9 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-NotificationCenter==7.2; platform_release >= "14.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_NotificationCenter-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (7.4 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-DeviceCheck==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_DeviceCheck-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.2 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ApplicationServices==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_ApplicationServices-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ContactsUI==7.2; platform_release >= "15.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_ContactsUI-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (6.0 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==7.2; platform_release >= "10.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_ServiceManagement-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.4 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-MediaAccessibility==7.2; platform_release >= "13.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_MediaAccessibility-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.8 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-SecurityFoundation==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_SecurityFoundation-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.1 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-SoundAnalysis==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_SoundAnalysis-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.3 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AuthenticationServices==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_AuthenticationServices-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (8.6 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreHaptics==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreHaptics-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.4 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==7.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyobjc->PyAutoGUI) (7.2)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==7.2; platform_release >= "10.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_OpenDirectory-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-OSLog==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_OSLog-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (5.9 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreMIDI==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreMIDI-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (9.4 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-VideoToolbox==7.2; platform_release >= "12.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_VideoToolbox-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (9.5 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-MediaPlayer==7.2; platform_release >= "16.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_MediaPlayer-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-WebKit==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_WebKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (28 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-VideoSubscriberAccount==7.2; platform_release >= "18.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_VideoSubscriberAccount-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.7 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreServices==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreServices-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (27 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_SystemConfiguration-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (17 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreAudio==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreAudio-7.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (24 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CloudKit==7.2; platform_release >= "14.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CloudKit-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.2 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==7.2; platform_release >= "10.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreLocation-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (9.2 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ExternalAccessory==7.2; platform_release >= "17.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_ExternalAccessory-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (6.7 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-libdispatch==7.2; platform_release >= "12.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_libdispatch-7.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (12 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Security==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Security-7.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (30 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-SafariServices==7.2; platform_release >= "15.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_SafariServices-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (6.0 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-DVDPlayback==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_DVDPlayback-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN==7.2; platform_release >= "10.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreWLAN-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (8.3 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-iTunesLibrary==7.2; platform_release >= "10.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_iTunesLibrary-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-KernelManagement==7.2; platform_release >= "20.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_KernelManagement-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.2 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==7.2; platform_release >= "9.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Collaboration-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.4 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-MetalPerformanceShaders==7.2; platform_release >= "17.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_MetalPerformanceShaders-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (17 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Social==7.2; platform_release >= "12.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Social-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-IOSurface==7.2; platform_release >= "10.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_IOSurface-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.3 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-SystemExtensions==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_SystemExtensions-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ColorSync==7.2; platform_release >= "17.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_ColorSync-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_SearchKit-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.3 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-UserNotifications==7.2; platform_release >= "18.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_UserNotifications-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (7.1 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Intents==7.2; platform_release >= "16.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Intents-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (18 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreAudioKit==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreAudioKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (5.7 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ModelIO==7.2; platform_release >= "15.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_ModelIO-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (13 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Accounts==7.2; platform_release >= "12.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Accounts-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Quartz==7.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyobjc->PyAutoGUI) (7.2)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_AddressBook-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_PreferencePanes-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.2 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-SceneKit==7.2; platform_release >= "11.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_SceneKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (20 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-FinderSync==7.2; platform_release >= "14.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_FinderSync-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.3 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-UniformTypeIdentifiers==7.2; platform_release >= "20.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_UniformTypeIdentifiers-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Automator==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Automator-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Contacts==7.2; platform_release >= "15.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Contacts-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (9.2 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CryptoTokenKit==7.2; platform_release >= "14.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CryptoTokenKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (9.4 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ReplayKit==7.2; platform_release >= "20.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_ReplayKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (7.0 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Virtualization==7.2; platform_release >= "20.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Virtualization-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (6.2 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AdServices==7.2; platform_release >= "20.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_AdServices-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.0 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-SecurityInterface==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_SecurityInterface-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (7.8 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreMedia==7.2; platform_release >= "11.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreMedia-7.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (19 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-UserNotificationsUI==7.2; platform_release >= "20.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_UserNotificationsUI-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-MetalKit==7.2; platform_release >= "15.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_MetalKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (6.6 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ScreenTime==7.2; platform_release >= "20.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_ScreenTime-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.1 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==7.2; platform_release >= "10.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_AppleScriptObjC-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ExecutionPolicy==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_ExecutionPolicy-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.2 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-MetalPerformanceShadersGraph==7.2; platform_release >= "20.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_MetalPerformanceShadersGraph-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.7 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-NetworkExtension==7.2; platform_release >= "15.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_NetworkExtension-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Network==7.2; platform_release >= "18.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Network-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (13 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==7.2; platform_release >= "9.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_InputMethodKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-SpriteKit==7.2; platform_release >= "13.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_SpriteKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-PassKit==7.2; platform_release >= "20.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_PassKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (8.7 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreData==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreData-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (12 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Vision==7.2; platform_release >= "17.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Vision-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreMotion==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreMotion-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.4 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreMediaIO==7.2; platform_release >= "11.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreMediaIO-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==7.2; platform_release >= "9.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_DictionaryServices-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==7.2; platform_release >= "9.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_InstantMessage-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-PushKit==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_PushKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (6.1 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-BusinessChat==7.2; platform_release >= "18.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_BusinessChat-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.9 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreML==7.2; platform_release >= "17.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreML-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (8.3 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CallKit==7.2; platform_release >= "20.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CallKit-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.2 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-LocalAuthentication==7.2; platform_release >= "14.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_LocalAuthentication-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreText==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreText-7.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (24 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ClassKit==7.2; platform_release >= "20.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_ClassKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (6.1 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-FileProviderUI==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_FileProviderUI-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.1 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-LinkPresentation==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_LinkPresentation-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.2 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Speech==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Speech-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (6.6 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_InstallerPlugins-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.3 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-GameController==7.2; platform_release >= "13.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_GameController-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (8.7 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CFNetwork-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (12 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AVKit==7.2; platform_release >= "13.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_AVKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (7.4 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-GameCenter==7.2; platform_release >= "12.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_GameCenter-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (12 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Metal==7.2; platform_release >= "15.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Metal-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (27 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==7.2; platform_release >= "9.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_FSEvents-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (9.1 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-MediaToolbox==7.2; platform_release >= "13.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_MediaToolbox-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (8.4 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-GameKit==7.2; platform_release >= "12.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_GameKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (15 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_AppleScriptKit-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.8 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CalendarStore==7.2; platform_release >= "9.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CalendarStore-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Accessibility==7.2; platform_release >= "20.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Accessibility-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (5.4 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreSpotlight==7.2; platform_release >= "17.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreSpotlight-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (7.1 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_LatentSemanticMapping-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==7.2; platform_release >= "9.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_ScriptingBridge-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (6.8 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-MapKit==7.2; platform_release >= "13.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_MapKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (14 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-MultipeerConnectivity==7.2; platform_release >= "14.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_MultipeerConnectivity-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (9.0 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_SyncServices-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-FileProvider==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_FileProvider-7.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AutomaticAssessmentConfiguration==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_AutomaticAssessmentConfiguration-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (6.2 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-DiskArbitration==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_DiskArbitration-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.3 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Photos==7.2; platform_release >= "15.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Photos-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (9.1 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-DiscRecordingUI==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_DiscRecordingUI-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.2 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreBluetooth==7.2; platform_release >= "14.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_CoreBluetooth-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (9.9 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-MediaLibrary==7.2; platform_release >= "13.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_MediaLibrary-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.8 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-GameplayKit==7.2; platform_release >= "15.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_GameplayKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (8.5 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ImageCaptureCore==7.2; platform_release >= "10.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_ImageCaptureCore-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (12 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-PencilKit==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_PencilKit-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.1 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-PhotosUI==7.2; platform_release >= "15.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_PhotosUI-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (7.9 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-IMServicePlugIn==7.2; platform_release >= "11.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_IMServicePlugIn-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (9.7 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-QuickLookThumbnailing==7.2; platform_release >= "19.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_QuickLookThumbnailing-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.5 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_ExceptionHandling-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.3 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-MLCompute==7.2; platform_release >= "20.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_MLCompute-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_LaunchServices-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.3 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_DiscRecording-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (12 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-EventKit==7.2; platform_release >= "12.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_EventKit-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.6 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AVFoundation==7.2; platform_release >= "11.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_AVFoundation-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (39 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-StoreKit==7.2; platform_release >= "11.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_StoreKit-7.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (8.5 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-NetFS==7.2; platform_release >= "10.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_NetFS-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.7 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AppTrackingTransparency==7.2; platform_release >= "20.0"
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_AppTrackingTransparency-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.2 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAutoGUI, pymsgbox, PyTweening, pyscreeze, pygetwindow, mouseinfo, pyrect, pyperclip
Failed to build PyAutoGUI pymsgbox PyTweening pyscreeze pygetwindow mouseinfo pyrect pyperclip

  WARNING: Building wheel for PyAutoGUI failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/kahsengho/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/4d/0d'
  WARNING: Building wheel for pymsgbox failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/kahsengho/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/91'
  WARNING: Building wheel for PyTweening failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/kahsengho/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/e7'
  WARNING: Building wheel for pyscreeze failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/kahsengho/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/f7'
  WARNING: Building wheel for pygetwindow failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/kahsengho/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/91'
  WARNING: Building wheel for mouseinfo failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/kahsengho/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/d1'
  WARNING: Building wheel for pyrect failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/kahsengho/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/d1'
  WARNING: Building wheel for pyperclip failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/kahsengho/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/7f'
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pymsgbox, pyscreeze which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1; however, version 21.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Don't use the system Python interpreter. Create a virtual environment and use it for the project.

Comment: What do you mean? I used pycharm's python interpreter. Does that not work, if so what should I do?

Comment: PyCharm has no Python interpreter built-in. You have some interpreter installed globally in your system (`/usr/local/bin/python3.8`) set as a project interpreter in the IDE. Installing packages on this interpreter requires admin permissions. You can do it with sudo `sudo pip3.8 install pyautogui`. But a better solution is to create a virtual environment and use it as a project interpreter instead, see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html